# Ubuntu 20.04.3 doesn´t work with the huaweii matebook 14 d 's fingerprint reader

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I need some help with the fingerprint, i´d like to use the fingerprint reader but doesn´t work.

```
fprintd-enroll
```

Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

and with `fwupdmgr get-devices`

```
BoDE-WXX9
│
├─511BS0512HB:
│
│     Device ID:          71b677ca0f1bc2c5b804fa1d59e52064ce589293
│     Summary:            NVM Express solid state drive
│     Current version:    ECFO15.5
│     Vendor:             Phison Electronics Corporation (NVME:0x1987)
│     Update Error:       Cannot install update when not on AC power
│     GUID:               38d64a8a-1cd1-589c-9f70-b0b9c4379c43
│                         94e27f4a-86e3-53a2-a728-18db5dd2be18
│                         8cb1e2fe-eb01-5508-9fb3-98add4bb7c34
│                         a44eb54c-5441-56f2-8cc0-5e48964c6457
│                         f3390fde-251b-5077-8380-286c25c55ab0│     Device Flags:       • Internal device│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs shutdown after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│                         • Updatable
│   
│
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          a45df35ac0e948ee180fe216a5f703f32dda163f
│
│
│ │   Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
│ │   Current version:    65560
│
│ │   Minimum Version:    65559
│
│ │   Vendor:             HUAWEI (DMI:HUAWEI)
│ │   Update State:       Success
│ 
│ │   Update Error:       Cannot install update when not on AC power
│ │   GUID:               f0ebda53-45f7-4097-be9c-5c561ef85aa1
│ │                       230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │ 
│ └─UEFI dbx:
│       Device ID:        362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
│       Summary:          UEFI revocation database
│       Current version:  270
│       Minimum Version:  270
│       Vendor:           UEFI:Linux Foundation
│       Install Duration: 1 second
│       GUID:             c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742
│                         f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731
│       Device Flags:     • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Only version upgrades are allowed
│                         • Signed Payload
│     
└─UEFI Device Firmware:
     Device ID:          349bb341230b1a86e5effe7dfe4337e1590227bd
     Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
     Current version:    1898
     Minimum Version:    1000
     Vendor:             DMI:HUAWEI
     Update State:       Success
     Update Error:       Cannot install update when not on AC power
     GUID:               865d322c-6ac7-4734-b43e-55db5a557d63
     Device Flags:        • Internal device
                          • System requires external power source
                          • Needs a reboot after installation
                          • Device is usable for the duration of the update
                          • Updatable
```